# Javascript works in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Clicking the button on the site hides the element in Chrome but not in Firefox, why is this?

-http://209.236.124.197/smart/

The javascript on the page:

```
var TimeToFade = 1000.0;

function fade(eid)
{
  var element = document.getElementById(eid);
  if(element == null)
    return;


  if(element.FadeState == null)
  {
    if(element.style.opacity == null || element.style.opacity == '' 
       || element.style.opacity == '1')
      element.FadeState = 2;
    else
      element.FadeState = -2;
  }

  if(element.FadeState == 1 || element.FadeState == -1)
  {
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? -1 : 1;
    element.FadeTimeLeft = TimeToFade - element.FadeTimeLeft;
  }
  else
  {
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 2 ? -1 : 1;
    element.FadeTimeLeft = TimeToFade;
    setTimeout("animateFade(" + new Date().getTime() + ",'" + eid + "')", 33);
  }  
}

function animateFade(lastTick, eid)
{  
  var curTick = new Date().getTime();
  var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

  var element = document.getElementById(eid);

  if(element.FadeTimeLeft <= elapsedTicks)
  {
    element.style.opacity = element.FadeState == 1 ? '1' : '0';
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = ' + (element.FadeState == 1 ? '100' : '0') + ')';
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? 2 : -2;
    return;
  }

  element.FadeTimeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
  var newOpVal = element.FadeTimeLeft/TimeToFade;
  if(element.FadeState == 1)
    newOpVal = 1 - newOpVal;

  element.style.opacity = newOpVal;
  element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = ' + (newOpVal*100) + ')';

  setTimeout("animateFade(" + curTick + ",'" + eid + "')", 33);
}
```

Comment: can you post you not-working code here rather than showing a url

Comment: Please, specify what you want to get and what didn't work in FF? "Go" button works clearly in FF 12.0 and Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m

Comment: Clicking on the button does not do anything in FF while the element disappears in chrome

Comment: Do you see anything in Error Console ?

Comment: No, everything is blank besides GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the browser - this code works in firefox. Have you tried shift+refreshing?

Comment: restarting firefox fixed the problem, sorry for everyone's trouble

Comment: shift-refresh did not work though